# Having trouble with regex groups

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> a = re.search('(\\d+h)?(\\d+m)?(\\d+s)?', 'in 1h15m')
>>> a.groups()
(None, None, None)
>>> a = re.search('.*(\\d+h)?(\\d+m)?(\\d+s)?', 'in 1h15m')
>>> a.groups()
(None, None, None)
>>> a = re.search('...(\\d+h)?(\\d+m)?(\\d+s)?', 'in 1h15m')
>>> a.groups()
('1h', '15m', None)
```

Why is the '...' version the only one that populates 'groups'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why are we getting empty groups?**

First one - `a?a?a` matched with `"bbbaaa"`:

- Start matching on the first position.
- Try to match `a`, but can't find. That's Ok, it's optional, so match nothing. (x 3 times)
- Return a successful empty match, with no successful captured groups.

Second one - `.*a?a?a` matched with `"bbbaaa"`:

- match `.*` from the first position to the last position.
- Now we are at the end of the string.
- Try to match `a`, but can't find it. That's Ok, it's optional, so match nothing. (x 3 times)
- Return a successful match with all original text, with no successful captured groups.

**How to solve this issue?**

It is unclear what exactly you are trying to do, but you can match for:

```
\d+h(\d+m)?(\d+s)?|(\d+m)(\d+s)?|(\d+s)
```

This assures you match at least one element - at least on option is not optional. Then, the regex would fail to match if none of the groups is available. You can parse it in a second step to get the groups, or use the group alternation feature `(?|  | )` if it is supported.

Comment: So: an empty match (None, None, None) is correct, and found at the earliest input position.
`

Comment: @Joop - exactly! People often thin regex engine are greedy by default, and try to match the longest string possible. This is a good example that demonstrates why this isn't the case at all...

Comment: What about with `.*?` at the front? That's non-greedy, but still doesn't work. I feel like it should try to match as much as possible while not bowling over the possibility of the hms bits matching.

Comment: @Gary - That is exactly the common mistake I talk about in the comment! `.*?(\\d+h)?` - `.*?` can match `""`, followed by `(lalala)?` that can also match `""` - right on the first position. And this is it - a successful match! By the way - all flavors (languages) will behave the same here, this isn't special to Python - greediness does **not** refer to the whole match, only to the `.*` before it. However, it will work with anchors: `^.*?(a)?$`, if the time is always at the end...

Comment: The frustrating bit is that I know all about this problem. I've been using regex almost daily for most a decade, and I've run into this problem, and even explained it to others many times, yet I still occasionally run into it, and it doesn't look like it :) This is a case where greediness and non-greediness both can't do what I want. I don't want to have to guarantee hours, because it can also just be minutes, or just seconds, or hours and minutes, or hours and seconds, etc.

Comment: @Gary - Well, the pattern in my answer *tries* to handle these cases, but it might be missing a few edge cases. (I didn't test it too well)

Comment: Sometimes I'm amazed to find these situations, when I usually grok regex so well. It's hard to imagine that I can't ask for a possible combination of 3 optional things without writing out all permutations thereof. I guess the core of the issue is that unlike 99% of the regexes I use, this one is unbounded to anything, and that causes problems. At any rate, I appreciate all your efforts, Kobi. Thanks.

Comment: @Gary - You don't always have to write all combinations. Some flavors (like .net) allow you to ispect and check whether groups matched or not. Still, I think this one is shorter `:)`  Thanks!

Comment: True. I think you would only need to write the 3 bounded versions, with the optional bits hanging off of them. It makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for your patience in the midst of my bewilderment and frustration.

Comment: Vim version that works:

`\v(\d+h)(\d+m)?(\d+s)?|(\d+h)?(\d+m)(\d+s)?|(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)` - 3 of the same pattern, each with a different subset being non-optional.

Comment: And now I see finally what you mean, Kobi. Phwew. What a rollercoaster. If h exists, the first matches with either m or s, or both attached. The other matches don't need h, because it's taken care of. If no h, m matches with an optional s, and m is not needed in the next one, wherein s is all that's left. FINALLY I get it. Sheesh. I think it's time for bed. Thanks once again.